# show gap for missing date in geom area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to plot the time series of my data. However there are some gaps in the date value like in the example below. The following code produces the plot disregarding the missing date. How can I show the missing date i.e. show a gap between 2021-01-02 and 2021-01-04 and similarly 2021-01-06 and 2021-01-08.

```
library(tidyverse)
fake.data <- data.frame(
  varA = c(0.6,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.7), 
  varB = c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.2),
  varC = c(0.3,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1),
  start_date = as.Date(c('2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-04','2021-01-06','2021-01-08')),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

fake.data %>% 
    gather(variable, value,varA:varC) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = start_date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_area()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the easiest would be to fake the gaps, e.g., with geom_rect.

Consider that "gaps in data" are actually inherent to most use of line / area graphs - some purists might actually be totally against showing lines / areas for non-continuous measurements, because it suggests continuous measurements. Thus, because it is interpolated anyways, you could argue that you might as well not *need to show* those gaps.

```r
library(tidyverse)
fake.data <- data.frame(
  varA = c(0.6,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.7), 
  varB = c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.2),
  varC = c(0.3,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1),
  start_date = as.Date(c('2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-04','2021-01-06','2021-01-08'))
) %>% pivot_longer(cols = matches("^var"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value" )

ls_data <- setNames(fake.data %>%
  complete(start_date = full_seq(start_date, 1)) %>% 
  split(., is.na(.$variable)), c("vals", "missing")) 

ggplot(ls_data$vals, aes(x = start_date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_rect(data = ls_data$missing, aes(xmin = start_date-.5, xmax = start_date+.5,
                                    ymin = 0, ymax = Inf), fill = "white") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Considering the above - I'd possibly favour not explicitly showing the gaps, but to show the measurements more explicitly. E.g., with geom_point.

```
fake.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = start_date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_point(position = "stack") +
  geom_line(position = "stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

is this close to what you wish ?

```
todateseq<-fake.data %>%
select(start_date) %>% 
pull

first <- min(todateseq)
last <- max(todateseq)

date_seq <- seq.Date(first,last,by='day')
fake.data2 <- data.frame(start_date=date_seq) %>%
left_join(fake.data,by='start_date')

fake.data2 %>% 
gather(variable, value,varA:varC) %>%
mutate(value=ifelse(is.na(value),0,value)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = start_date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
geom_area(na.rm = F,position = position_stack())
```